# Why is the Windows standalone Slack app stuck at "reconnecting..."?

Tags: windows

I prefer to run it outside the browser -- that way it has its own tab on the taskbar, as opposed to being 1 tab out of dozens in the browser. But since
last Friday, it's been stuck on "reconnecting..." even after restarts.

How can I fix this? Getting the org to look for an alternative
communication program is currently not an option.

Comment: Bring up Task Manager and look for any running instances of slack.exe. If you find any, kill them and then try restarting the app.

Comment: Thanks. That did it. There was also an extra slacky octothorpe in the notifications bar. Right-click-quit was sufficient.

Comment: Definitely didn't help me. There are 5 instances of slack.exe running, whenever you start the app, but they all get stopped when I quit the app. When I start it again - reconnecting still hangs. I also tried going to the browser and explicitly logging out there, starting the app as an admin, turning off the firewall - no help yet. So, the 57MB chat app was deinstalled.

Comment: Ok, I had to try to install it again - the same problem persisted. But then I went around and start clicking on buttons that are there, on search field etc and then Slack app threw me a 500 error like "You've found a Glitch!" and a pic of a nice forest with piggies and then I was able to go to my wanted board. So, 57MB (zipped!) chat monster remains installed for some more time.

Comment: Anyone running into a situation where the app won't open at all? That's what I'm seeing and so, killing slack.exe won't work. I'm hoping it's not V8-related.

Answer (score 11):

Most likely you need to clear your app settings. in the app click the top menu **Help > Reset App Data**

This did the trick for me.  Note that all you will need to reconnect all accounts

Got this from http://www.cpierce.org/2015/09/slack-wont-open-or-you-need-to-clear-your-settings-from-a-computer/

Comment: You can try *Help > Clear Cache and Restart* before that. It worked for me and I didn't have to reconnect all accounts.

Answer (score 3):

Just restarting the app also works for me. But the not-so-obvious part is that closing the windows does not close the app. you need to go to the hidden icons in system tray in the taskbar and close it from there too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a perfect connection on Slack web but have connectivity issues on Slack app, try closing any apps that might be proxying your IP address.

My issue was resolved by closing Fiddler, an HTTP web debugger that I had open for some API testing.

Comment: Have experienced this with Fiddler, also having "localhost" in my proxy exclusion list caused the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got this connection error because Avast, my anti-virus software, started blocking Slack.

If you are using Avast, you can disable all shields by right clicking on the task bar icon/Avast Control Shields/Disable for 10 minutes and then click "Ok, stop" on the pop-up.  then restart slack from within the slack app:  help/troubleshooting/clear cache and restart.

This enabled slack to connect, so I then went into Avast and disabled each shield one by one until I found the issue.  For me, it was the firewall shield.  I enabled Slack in that shield and all is well again.